# Best way to convert unsigned char * to int?

Tags: c, string

Hello I have an `unsigned char *` that looks (after printf) like this (it's a SHA-1 hash):

```
n\374\363\327=\3103\231\361P'o]Db\251\360\316\203
```

I need to convert this `unsigned char *` to an `unsigned int`, what do you think it would be the best way to do it ? I have some ideas, but I'm not a C expert so wanted to see someone else ideas before trying my own stuff.

Comment: That's not an `unsigned char *` you've got there, unless you've got a machine with a really weird architecture.  You could easily have an `unsigned char *` pointing to your value.  Exactly what do you want to convert this to, and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you need a conversion? It's a 160 bit long digest. Digests are used only in two ways:

You print a digest with something like

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    printf("%2x", digest[i]);
}
```

and compare against another digest with something like

```
for (i = 0, equals = 1; i < 20; ++i) {
    if (a[i] != b[i]) {
        equals = 0;
    }
}
```

It works just fine the way it is as a 20-byte long array of bytes. You don't have to worry about endianness, word length, nothing.

Comment: The problem is that a SHA-1 String is 160 bytes... what I'm thinking is I could use an array of 5 32bit ints to hold the whole SHA-1 string and make a dedicated Class to handle the comparison operations etc.

Comment: @Mr. Gando:  What's the difference between an array of 20 characters and an array of 5 ints, for practical purposes?  It's not like you're using the ints as ints, just as 20 bytes of storage.  Wrapping a digest in a class is a good idea, but using an array of ints rather than characters is pointless.

Comment: @David: I agree. Besides, chars are (almost) always 8 bit long (you can always check CHAR_BIT, if you really need to be uber-portable), whereas unsigned ints can have different sizes on different machines, packed in different byte order etc. Extra complexity for little gain.

Comment: @ David : What if for your particular implementation you used the ints as ints ?

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's more than 4 bytes, so if your system uses 32 bits for an unsigned int you can't do it without potentially losing information. IOW, it will have to be a hash of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

That's 160 bits, so would be hard to fit in a single unsigned int. However, it'd certainly be possible to fit it into an array of unsigned ints.

Something like this (ugly, makes a couple of assumptions about machine architecture, should probably use CHAR_BITS and a couple of other things compile-time to have the right constants, but should be enough as a proof-of-concept):

```
unsigned int (*convert)(unsigned char *original)
{
  unsigned int *rv = malloc(5*sizeof(unsigned int));
  char *tp = original;

  for (rvix=0;rvix<5;rvix++) {
    rv[rvix] = *(tp++)<<24;
    rv[rvix] |= *(tp++)<<16;
    rv[rvix] |= *(tp++)<<8;
    rv[rvix] |= *(tp++);
  }

  return rv;
}
```

Comment: I think that your code got cut ? could you re-paste that ? :-)

Comment: Yes, classic case of "oops, < introduces a tag".